# How to release selection in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I selected a space using the "Quick Selection Tool" in Photoshop, I did what I wanted to do with it and now I want to release this selection and do something else.

How can I release the selection?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Comment: This question is better asked on [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl+D or click somewhere on the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.